# vimtutor: command not found

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vim

My first time trying to pull up `vimtutor` fails. I get a `vimtutor: command not found` message. Strangely, running `vim` works fine.

I've never installed Vim on my own, I just found it working when I type `vim` in. But for some reason `vimtutor` doesn't work. I'm running this from the Git Bash command prompt, even on the Windows command prompt `vim` and `vimtutor` both fail in the same way.

Comment: There are some alternate instructions to opening     vimtutor.http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_01.html#01.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows and intend to use Vim for general editing (i.e. not just as a commit message editor for Git), I recommend to install the full Windows version (from http://www.vim.org/download.php). Then, you can launch the Vim Tutor from `%ProgramFiles%\vim\vim74\vimtutor.bat`.